# Вывод надписи на столбике Chart js

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Все привет, в первые сталкиваюсь с Chart Js и сразу же встал в тупик. Требуется вывести данные из базы данных mysql сделать подсчеты в php и вывести график, все сделано по плану и работает на отлично за исключением одного. Не могу разобраться как вывести к примеру переменную $comanda1f в само тело столбца, что бы цифры наглядно демонстрировали разницу в показателях. Сам код

```js
<div style="position:absolute; top:800px; left:10px; width:900px; height:600px;">
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
<script>

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Команда А", "Команда М", "Команда Я", "Команда К"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Рейтинг бригады',
            data: [  <?php echo $comanda1f; ?>,<?php echo $comanda2f ?>,<?php echo $comanda3f ?>,<?php echo $comanda4f ?>],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(10, 207, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(55, 20, 176, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 210, 0, 1)',
 
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(10, 207, 0, 1)',
                'rgba(55, 20, 176, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 210, 0, 1)',

            ],
            borderWidth: 3
        }]
  
    },

    options: {
   legend: {
      display: false
    },
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        beginAtZero: true,
        scaleLabel: {
            labelString: 'Month'
        },
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            min: 0,
            autoSkip: false
        }
    }]
}
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: "В тело столбца" - это куда?

Comment: @Kain на верху прикрепил картинку, примерно вот так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631354/how-to-display-data-values-on-chart-js). Вас интересует метод onAnimationComplete.

ctx.fillText(text, x, y) - создает текст в координатах x, y. Проходим по всем точкам и создаем для каждой текст.

Так же там упоминается [плагин](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) для chart.js.

```js
var chartData = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "#79D1CF",
            strokeColor: "#79D1CF",
            data: [60, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(chartData, {
    showTooltips: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = this.scale.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
        this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
                ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y + 20);
            });
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nnnick/Chart.js/v1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <canvas id="myChart2" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
```